# Opencv feed keeps loading after use, jupyter notebook kernel died. I am guessing that the opencv has a problem but I don't know how to solve it

Tags: python, tensorflow, opencv, jupyter, conda

[Python quit unexpectedly. The kernel appears to have died. It will restart automatically.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9pMAP.png)

(Device: MacBook Air M1)
I was collecting keypoints for training an action detection program (https://youtu.be/doDUihpj6ro) :

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

Set mediapipe model 
with mp_holistic.Holistic(min_detection_confidence=0.5, min_tracking_confidence=0.5) as holistic:
    
    for action in actions:
        # Loop through sequences aka videos
        for sequence in range(no_sequences):
            # Loop through video length aka sequence length, each frame, 30 frames of keypoints for each video
            for frame_num in range(sequence_length):

                # Read feed
                ret, frame = cap.read()

                # Make detections
                image, results = mediapipe_detection(frame, holistic)
print the results

                # Draw landmarks
                draw_styled_landmarks(image, results)
                
                # NEW Apply wait logic
                if frame_num == 0: 
                    cv2.putText(image, 'STARTING COLLECTION', (120,200), 
                               cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 1, (0,255, 0), 4, cv2.LINE_AA)
                    cv2.putText(image, 'Collecting frames for {} Video Number {}'.format(action, sequence), (15,12), 
                               cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5, (0, 0, 255), 1, cv2.LINE_AA)
                    # Show to screen
                    cv2.imshow('OpenCV Feed', image)
                    cv2.waitKey(1200)
                else: 
                    cv2.putText(image, 'Collecting frames for {} Video Number {}'.format(action, sequence), (15,12), 
                               cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5, (0, 0, 255), 1, cv2.LINE_AA)
                    # Show to screen
                    cv2.imshow('OpenCV Feed', image)
                
                # NEW Export keypoints
                keypoints = extract_keypoints(results)
                npy_path = os.path.join(DATA_PATH, action, str(sequence), str(frame_num))
                np.save(npy_path, keypoints)

                # Break gracefully
                if cv2.waitKey(10) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
                    break
                    
    cap.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

After I run this code and recorded my data(videos), my opencv feed kept loading (the rainbow circle in Macbook). WHen I ran the cell below, python quit unexpectedly and the kernel appears to have died.

```
 # Training Model
# Preprocess Data
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

from tensorflow.keras.utils import to_categorical
```

I read up online and someone who faced problems with opencv solved it by creating a new conda environment. This is what i tried and got in terminal:

```
conda create --name myenv opencv-env python=3.6
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with repodata from current_repodata.json, will retry with next repodata source.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - opencv-env

Current channels:

  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/osx-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/osx-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch

To search for alternate channels that may provide the conda package you're
looking for, navigate to

    https://anaconda.org

and use the search bar at the top of the page.
```

Comment: maybe put code in file and run it as normal script without using `juputer`

Comment: There are multiple questions in one. One is about the issue with creating the environment. The other one is the crashing kernel.

Comment: For the environment issue, Is `opencv-env` supposed to be the name of the environment you want to create?